# How to retrieve the date into three dropdown list?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a birthdate field which is optional after inserting a record into clients table.

the default value will is "000-00-00" after insert.

Now, I want to edit the record in the table and would like to get the value of the birth_date field into three dropdown list.

The three dropdown list are Day, Month, and Year.

If there is no birthdate the selected value of the three dropdown should be "Day", "Month", and "Year".

I tried the following code and don't know if this is the best way.

```
$dateValue = '0000-00-00';
$year = explode("-", $dateValue);

if ($year[0] == "0000") {
    $selected_year = "Year";
            $selected_month = "Month";
            $selected_day = "Day";
}else{
    $selected_year = date("Y",strtotime($user['birth_date']));
}
```

If there is a better way for this, please let me know.

btw, I'm using codeigniter.

Comment: You may get further here if you suggest what is actually *wrong* with your code, and ask for a way to fix it.  Asking if there is a better way is likely to elicit debate, which is not productive in StackOverflow's Q&A format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing your test too late, it is much simpler to do it directly on $dateValue. Also, you can simplify the code by making use of the [list](http://www.php.net/list) function:-

```
$dateValue = '0000-00-0';
if($dateValue == '0000-00-00'){
    $values = array('Year', 'Month', 'Day');
} else {
    $values = explode('-', $dateValue);
}
list($selected_year, $selected_month, $selected_day) = $values;

var_dump($selected_year);
var_dump($selected_month);
var_dump($selected_day);
```

Gives the following output:-

```
string 'Year' (length=4)
string 'Month' (length=5)
string 'Day' (length=3)
```

Changing the first line to:-

```
$dateValue = '2012-11-3';
```

Gives:-

```
string '2012' (length=4)
string '11' (length=2)
string '3' (length=1)
```

Personally, I would hide this all away in a function to improve readability:-

```
function getValues($dateValue = '0000-00-00'){
    if($dateValue == '0000-00-00'){
        $values = array('Year', 'Month', 'Day');
    } else {
        $values = explode('-', $dateValue);
    }
    return $values;
}
```

Then use it like this:-

```
list($selected_year, $selected_month, $selected_day) = getValues('2012-11-03');

var_dump($selected_year);
var_dump($selected_month);
var_dump($selected_day);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm just worried about the date format if it will change from Y/m/d to something without my knowledge. Is this possible?

Comment: That depends on where it is coming from. If you can control the format form the date source, then do so.

Answer (score 0):

well my suggestion is to use date_format mysql function to get year,day and month in your query like this

```
select *,DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y') as selected_year,
DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%d') as selected_day,
DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%c') as selected_month 
from user_table;
```

for more information date_format please check this link 
[Date_format](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

or mysql doc